# android canvas how scale and center rectangle

Tags: android

I'm writing simple board game for Android. I want to make game better suited for different screen resolution. So I trying to scale board (9x9 rectangles). My questions is how to scale board or rectangle and maintain center ?

I'm attaching simple example with rectangle and picture.

```
 public RectangleExample(Context c)
    {
        super(c);
    }

    final int width = 100 ;
    final int height = 100 ;
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.scale(1.5f, 1.5f);
        Paint paint = new Paint() ;
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        int startX = (getWidth() - width) / 2 ;
        int startY = (getHeight() - height) / 2 ;
        Rect r = new Rect(startX, startY, startX + width, startY + height);
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    }
```

[image]

Picture shows after scaling rectangle lost center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move (translate) coordinate system origin into the center of view 
and only after that apply scaling

something like this

```
final int width = 100;
final int height = 100;
final Paint paint = new Paint();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    canvas.scale(1.5f, 1.5f);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    int startX = -width / 2;
    int startY = -height / 2;
    Rect r = new Rect(startX, startY, startX + width, startY + height);
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

or you can set coordinates of pivot point

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.scale(1.5f, 1.5f, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2); // <---- here is
    Paint paint = new Paint() ;
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    int startX = (getWidth() - width) / 2 ;
    int startY = (getHeight() - height) / 2 ;
    Rect r = new Rect(startX, startY, startX + width, startY + height);
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
}
```